# Amazon SES asking to verify email of every recipient

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using SES to create a newsletter service. I have a frontend website, on which user can sign-up by providing their email id. I capture that email id in database and use that to send emails periodically using SES.

My question is do I need to send a verify customer email id before I start sending them newsletter? Is it a restriction of sandbox environment and will it be resolved once I get production access? I have tried with different new email ids but every time it fails saying email id is not verified.

According to [Creating and verifying identities in Amazon SES - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/creating-identities.html), it mentions to use a verified domain, so I have tried with verified domain as well (although still in sandbox environment).

Comment: This is a restriction of the sandbox environment. You have to verify your own domains of course. But as long as you are in sandbox, you can also only *send* to you your own verified domains. This restriction will go away, once you are in production. In principle, you don't need to verify receiver addresses at all (in production). But I'd strongly suggest to do so and don't send any mails to unverified addresses, because they may bounce. And if you have too many bounces, your SES account may get locked

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a restriction of sandbox environment and will it be resolved once I get production access?

That's correct. As mentioned [in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/verify-addresses-and-domains.html):

*If your account is still in the Amazon SES sandbox, you also need to verify any email addresses which you plan on sending email to*

therefore when you are *not* in the sandbox environment, this limitation does not apply.